# GridView Sorting event is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

GridView Sorting and Paging are works fine when I set EnableSotringAndPagingCallbacks to false.
 however when I set it to true the sort event does not fire (the paging works fine).

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is actually the correct behavior.

> By default, when a sorting or paging
>   operation is performed, the GridView
>   control posts back to the server to
>   perform the operation. When the
>   EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks
>   property is set to true, a service is
>   called on the client to perform
>   sorting and paging operations, which
>   eliminates the need to post back to
>   the server.

Read this for more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.enablesortingandpagingcallbacks.aspx

Comment: How can i achieve the sorting when EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks is set to true?

Comment: Never had to actually do this, but according to a tutorial I found, you'll have to write some javascript sorting routines. http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?id=106