# I want to do sorting on based on column of gridview, but event is not firing when I click on header of HeaderTemplete

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have created one gridview with custom column and want to perform sorting on them. When I click on column then no event is firing for sorting.

Below is the code which I have written

For .aspx page

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdConfigureCustomers" runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-    BackColor="Aqua" Width="1300px"
        OnRowCommand="grdConfigureCustomers_RowCommand" OnRowEditing="grdConfigureCustomers_RowEditing"
        OnRowUpdating="grdConfigureCustomers_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="grdConfigureCustomers_RowCancelingEdit"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5"
        OnRowDeleting="grdConfigureCustomers_RowDeleting" ShowFooter="true" 
        onpageindexchanging="grdConfigureCustomers_PageIndexChanging"  OnSorting="grdConfigureCustomers_Sorting" AllowSorting="true">
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="AliceBlue" />
        <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Customer_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddCustomerId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span style="color:Red;">*</span>
                    </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

For .aspx.cs page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadCustomerConfigurationGridView();
        }

    }

    private void LoadCustomerConfigurationGridView()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = sqlHelper.GetCustomerListInformation();
        grdConfigureCustomers.DataSource = dt;
        grdConfigureCustomers.DataBind();
        Session["data"] = dt;

    }
private void LoadCustomerConfigurationGridView(string srtexpr, string direc)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = sqlHelper.GetCustomerListInformation();
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.Sort = srtexpr + " " + direc;
        grdConfigureCustomers.DataSource = dv;
        grdConfigureCustomers.DataBind();
        Session["data"] = dt;

    }
protected void grdConfigureCustomers_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.SortExpression)
        {
            case "DateLogged":
                if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    LoadCustomerConfigurationGridView("DateLogged", "ASC");
                }
                else
                {
                    LoadCustomerConfigurationGridView();
                }

                break;

        }
    }
```

Please let me know what I missed for sorting. Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this article- http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2013/05/gridview-sorting-on-header-click-with.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `SortExpression` property in the TemplateField like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer ID" SortExpression="Customer_ID">
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug and set breakpoint in `grdConfigureCustomers_Sorting` method? Is that method called when you click the header?

Comment: Yes I tried to debug, when i put break point in grdConfigureCustomers_Sorting  it is not hiting.

Comment: Please try to set the `EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks` property to false explicitly, refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816230/gridview-sorting-event-is-not-firing

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable sorting. `EnableSorting="true"` in your asp.net:Gridview.

Comment: I have given    AllowSorting = "true" and EnableSorting is not the property of gridview. I didnt get you.